# How much thrust is required to move a boat of 120 kg / 265 pounds to a speed of ....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

How much thrust is required to move a boat of 120 kg / 265 pounds to a speed of 10 km / 6 miles per hour in 7 seconds.

I found the following:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust-to-weight_ratio
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-to-weight_ratio

which gives me some formulas, but its been a long time since I used any maths, and it was way beyond me, especially as there is a certain amount of drag caused by the water.

I do apologize if this question is not relevant to this website.

Comment: This might be better suited for the [physics.se] site, as the mathematics involved is kind of trivial. Then again, the physics is pretty elementary, too (except for estimating the drag, if you want to do that). Hint: don't try to look for a magic formula, but just calculate the relevant figures one step at a time: first the acceleration, then the force to produce it, then the work done (which requires the distance traveled; that's the only mathematically non-trivial part) and finally the power. Check at each step that your units stay consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SI units, the desired speed is $v = 10\cdot 1000/3600$ (meters per second). The desired acceleration over $7$ seconds (assuming it's uniform) is $v/7$. Given the mass of $120$ kg, you need the force of $120$ times the acceleration, that is 
$$120 \cdot 10 \cdot \frac{1000}{3600} \frac{1}{7}$$
(measured in Newton). Not much. (The speed of 10 km/hr isn't much, either.)

Comment: Thank you - I tried doing the calculations but I dont understand whether the 10 . 1000/3600 is 10.27778 or 10 times 1000/3600. I assume the latter and end up with 47.61905 SI. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I got too.  One km/hour is 1000/3600 meters per second. The result of 47.6 Newton was surprisingly low to me, but it seems correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I also got this - 47.6 newtons =
10.7009057 pounds force. I think the boat builder will understand all that. Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The equations you need are:

$F = ma$

(the thrust is a force $F$. $m$ is mass. $a$ is the acceleration)

and

$v = u + at$

where $v$ is final velocity, $u$ is initial velocity, $a$ is (constant) acceleration and $t$ is time.

Can you figure it out? Try it first, and post your difficulties in comments. I may expand on my answer then.

Comment: Deepak - thank you for trying to teach me. Unfortunately no - at my age I am struggling. I tried, and seemed to be going around in circles. I know what m is, v, u and t, but I still got lost.